# Construct an inherited class by calling both of parameterized parent class constructors

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, c++11

Here is a class:

```
class P1{
public:
    P1(int i){}
};
```

Here is another class:

```
class P2{
public:
    P2(int i){}
};
```

Here is a class that inherits from the two classes above:

```
class D: public P1, public P2{
    //?
};
```

Did I inheirt the constructors of the two classes as well?
How can I edit class D, so that I can construct the derived class in the following way:

```
D d(11,22);
```

Comment: No, you did not ___inherit___ the constructors. But you can ___access___ the base class constructors.

Comment: What you need is a [Member Initalizer list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor).

Comment: class P1: instead of A do you mean P1?

Comment: @spin_eight Of course he did. It's a typo.

Comment: You can [***inherit*** constructors](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting) with the new *tricks* of C++11. But in your case i wonder if it's possible because both base class constructors have the same signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class D : public P1, public P2
{
    public:
       D(int x, int y) : P1(x), P2(y) 
       {
       }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to do it,

```
class D: public P1, public P2{
    D(int x, int y) // Have your own constructor for the derived class
        : P1(x), P2(y) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructors **can`t** be **implicitly inherited**.
But to be able to use base class constructors use *member initialization syntax* as already proposed in the prevoius answers